# Variables from renderpage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have **index.cshtml** that looks like this

```
@RenderPage("header.cshtml")
@x
```

and on **header.cshtml** I have this

```
@{
var x="hello there"

}
```

the *x* value from **header.cshtml** is not being posted in **index.cshtml**.

I know there are other ways to do this such as helpers and functions
but how do I make this work ?

In classic asp this works and id like to follow the pattern.

Answer (score 10):

In your **index.cshtml** you can use in like this:

```
@RenderPage("header.cshtml", x)
```

And then on your **header.cshtml** you can get the value like this:

```
@Page[0]
```

On your `View`.

But better do it like this, since `Page` object is `Dynamic` type on `View`, **index.cshtml**:

```
@RenderPage("header.cshtml", new { MyParam = x})
```

And, **header.cshtml**:

```
@Page.MyParam
```

But I think better use `RenderPartial` method. Take a look at [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in) about it.